# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File media/StateData.csv does not exist: 'media/StateData.csv'

Tags: python, flask, heroku, deployment

I have deployed my flask app on heroku (http://bhuvnesh-app.herokuapp.com/). Its working fine on local but getting above error on heroku app logs.

**main.py**

```
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def covid_data():
    df=pd.read_csv('media/StateData.csv')
    .....
    .....
    return render_template('map.html',map=Map_Show._repr_html_())
```

[**file structure**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It8Gn.png)

Answer (score 0):

This could be just about anything. Couple of tips to try it out.
Heroku IIRC (it's been a couple of years) allow you to exec into a Dyno. You could exec in, and run the command locally to see if you get similar results.

Another option would be to log out the current directory (os.getcwd()), and listing the contents of the remote directory (glob.glob('media/*')).

Finally what is your local environment? Are you working on a case insensitive filesystem (like NTFS on Windows) locally? If so check that the filename on the FS is the same (case sensitive) as you have in your code.

Comment: Checkout this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/It8Gn.png here is the directory structure of my project. I am using windows NTFS